# What is the difference between interface and model in angular

Tags: angular, interface, model

I have a question, when can we use **interface** and when can we use **model** in angular
*i'm using angular 9*

Comment: The only difference between the two is that one is just a type which defines a structure while the other is a JSON structure but I'd say you'd use an interface in most cases unless for some reason you need to generate one or more object/s (class)